# How to allow users to opt out from data tracking tools?

Tags: analytics, data-analysis, ethics, cookies, ethical-design

Our team is implementing Hotjar and Google analytics so we can start tracking data to help us improve the user experience but I was thinking it would be ethical to allow users to opt out if they don't want to share data. I'm a big believer in that ethical design is important so I was researching how to do this but unfortunately I can't find anything online.

Does Google or Hotjar does it automatically or our team needs to develop something *(like the example I post below from the UK government)*? and if we need to develop this, how can we do this? Any help on how to build this is welcome!

Thank you so much in advance,

[image: Cookies on GOV.UK alert]

Comment: You might specifically research GDPR consent components. If your website uses plugins, there are likely plugins that have already been developed. GDPR consent is a good idea no matter what if you're tracking user behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using third party service like https://www.iubenda.com that manage all of this for you and give you legal covers. They also will provide a cookie plugin to manage all the various options and the user can then opt out whenever they want.

Otherwise you should manage all your cookie-realated third party scripts by hand and enabling them only when user gives consent.

What could be a possible implementation for the manual approach?
You could have a `modal` element (the modal should be activated with a toggle and always reachable in your app/website) with a `title` and a `description` that shortly describe the purpose of the modal and of the actions the user is gonna take. Inside the modal you could render
a list of composed elements, each `row` should have a text whith a descriptive short title of the option the user is gonna to manage for example `Measurements` (to indicate all script for tracking and analytics purposes) and a `switch` (from where you retrieve the boolean value of the user choice). Once you have your `jsonObject` with the user preferences, when the user presses a `Save and Continue` button then you should inject all the related scripts. Remember that each option should be well documented and the user should have the possibility to read a more detailed legally valid documented page where all the tools and scripts used and injected are presented and well described and also includes info such as `cookie name` - `Expiration date` and more stuff you can find by googling.

But again its gonna be a lot of work that is gonna require a lot of time, time that can be saved with a third-party service. There a lot of them just choose the one best suits your needs. I suggested Iubenda because has a very good reputation.

Hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note here is that this is a UX Design exchange and, as such, we cannot offer you valid advice on developing or building - We can only advise you on how best to go about understanding what considerations you need to take into account for your users. For more specific coding advice, you could try asking on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

As Izquierdo said in their comment, it's extremely important that you learn about GDPR. This will give you an understanding of what you *must* do and what you *can* do in regard to notifying users and allowing them to opt out of various combinations of cookies. If you are operating within any EU (plus some other) territories, **this is a legal requirement** wherever you are using cookies of any kind.

When it comes to the design of the UI for the opt-out process, there are many suppliers who provide out-of-the-box customisable solutions. The trade-off here is that, while they have already taken care of the legalities, design, and development, they do have a cost impact and are mostly delivered through third-party servers meaning that they could have an impact on your site performance/uptime.

If you choose to build your own solution then looking at how other people do it is a great way to start and you probably couldn't have picked a better one than a government website. I suggest also looking at public broadcasters and large multinational corporations too.

As with all things UX, it's also important to understand *your* particular users and how they will interact with this. Do they have any special requirements for interfaces?

Lastly, as this is a legal consideration, you will need to ensure that the UI is **fully** accessible by the terms required for every territory you intend to do business in.